# Validación de lista dentro de una lista

Tags: html, html5, lista, validación

Tengo un problema con la validación de un código, y es en cuanto a una lista anidada que tengo, que me muestra error diciendo que una etiqueta `ul` no puede ser hija de otra etiqueta `ul`, claro que esto lo entiendo pero si las listas anidadas existen y se utilizan, lo que no entiendo es por qué aún así me lanza este error el validador. Esta es la lista:

```html
<ul>
           <li>El príncipe feliz y otros cuentos</li>
                <ul>
            <li>El príncipe feliz</li>
            <li>El ruiseñor y la rosa</li>
            <li>El amigo fiel</li>
            <li>El famoso cohete</li>
                </ul>
           <li>El crimen de lord Arthur Savile y otras historias</li>
                <ul>
            <li>El crimen de lord Arthur Savile</li>
            <li>El fantasma de Canterville</li>
            <li>La esfinge sin secreto</li>
            <li>El modelo millonario</li>
            <li>El retrato del Sr. W. H.</li> 
                </ul>
           <li>Una casa de granadas</li>
                <ul>
            <li>El joven rey</li>
            <li>El cumpleaños de la infanta</li>
            <li>El pescador y su alma</li>
            <li>El niño estrella</li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
        <h3><em>Ensayos</em></h3>
        <ul>
           <li>Intenciones</li>
                <ul>
            <li>La decadencia de la mentira</li>
            <li>Pluma, lápiz y veneno</li>
            <li>El crítico artista</li>
              <li>La verdad sobre las máscaras</li>
                </ul>
           <li>El alma del hombre bajo el socialismo</li>
           <li>Frases y filosofías para uso de la juventud</li>
           <li>Algunas máximas para la instrucción de los súper-educados</li>
        </ul>
        <h3><em>Obras de Teatro</em></h3>
        <ul>
           <li>Vera o los nihilistas</li>
           <li>La duquesa de Padua</li>
           <li>El abanico de Lady Windermere </li>
           <li>Una mujer sin importancia </li>
           <li>Salomé</li>
           <li>Un marido ideal</li>
           <li>La importancia de llamarse Ernesto</li>
        </ul>
        <h3><em>Poemas</em></h3>
        <ul>
           <li>Ravenna</li>
           <li>Poemas</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Impression du Matin</li>
                    <li>Requiescat</li>
                </ul>
           <li>Poemas en prosa</li>
           <li>La esfinge</li>
           <li>Balada de la Cárcel de Reading</li>
        </ul>
        <h3><em>Prosas</em></h3>
        <ul>
           <li>El retrato de Dorian Gray</li>
           <li>De profundis</li>
           <li>Teleny o El reverso de la medalla</li>
  </ul>
```

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan proporcionar en este punto sería muy apreciada!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

las etiquetas hijas de la etiqueta `<ul>` deben de ser siempre `<li>`, por pura sintaxis.

Según el código que nos muestras tienes, dentro de las etiquetas `<ul>`, tanto etiquetas `<li>` como `<ul>`.

Te sugiero que las etiquetas `<ul>` hijas, las pongas dentro de etiquetas `<li>`.

Por ejemplo, y para desenrredar un poco:

```
 <ul>
        <li>
            <a>Poemas</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Neruda</li>
                <li>Benedetti</li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Si!!! Muchas gracias, acabo de publicar una respuesta también porque di con la solución y claro que tiene más lógica así!!! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)

Comment: Qué bien que la encontraste! De nada, gracias a ti por preguntar.

Answer (score 1):

El validador te saca error por que la forma correcta de usar una lista anidada es colocar los `<ul>` de segundo nivel dentro de los `<li>` pertenecientes al `<ul>` de primer nivel y así sucesivamente:

```html
<ul>
   <li>El príncipe feliz y otros cuentos
        <ul>
            <li>El príncipe feliz</li>
            <li>El ruiseñor y la rosa</li>
            <li>El amigo fiel</li>
            <li>El famoso cohete</li>
        </ul>
   </li>

   <li>El crimen de lord Arthur Savile y otras historias
        <ul>
            <li>El crimen de lord Arthur Savile</li>
            <li>El fantasma de Canterville</li>
            <li>La esfinge sin secreto</li>
            <li>El modelo millonario</li>
            <li>El retrato del Sr. W. H.</li> 
        </ul>
   </li>

   <li>Una casa de granadas
        <ul>
            <li>El joven rey</li>
            <li>El cumpleaños de la infanta</li>
            <li>El pescador y su alma</li>
            <li>El niño estrella</li>
        </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
<h3><em>Ensayos</em></h3>
<ul>
   <li>Intenciones
        <ul>
            <li>La decadencia de la mentira</li>
            <li>Pluma, lápiz y veneno</li>
            <li>El crítico artista</li>
            <li>La verdad sobre las máscaras</li>
        </ul>
   </li>

   <li>El alma del hombre bajo el socialismo</li>
   <li>Frases y filosofías para uso de la juventud</li>
   <li>Algunas máximas para la instrucción de los súper-educados</li>
</ul>
<h3><em>Obras de Teatro</em></h3>
<ul>
   <li>Vera o los nihilistas</li>
   <li>La duquesa de Padua</li>
   <li>El abanico de Lady Windermere </li>
   <li>Una mujer sin importancia </li>
   <li>Salomé</li>
   <li>Un marido ideal</li>
   <li>La importancia de llamarse Ernesto</li>
</ul>
<h3><em>Poemas</em></h3>
<ul>
   <li>Ravenna</li>
   <li>Poemas
        <ul>
            <li>Impression du Matin</li>
            <li>Requiescat</li>
        </ul>
   </li>

   <li>Poemas en prosa</li>
   <li>La esfinge</li>
   <li>Balada de la Cárcel de Reading</li>
</ul>
<h3><em>Prosas</em></h3>
<ul>
   <li>El retrato de Dorian Gray</li>
   <li>De profundis</li>
   <li>Teleny o El reverso de la medalla</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Si, tienes toda la razón. Después de quemarme la cabeza fue que se me ocurrió hacer eso por pura lógica y para probar y se me resolvió el problema. Muchas gracias por responder mi pregunta!!!

Comment: Que bien,si la respuesta ayudó en tu solución considera marcarla aceptada para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien tiene problema con esto, después de quemarme más el cerebro pensando que era algo más importante, probé poniendo una etiqueta `li` antes de las nuevas listas quería anidar y se resolvió el problema! Acá está un ejemplo:

```html
         <ul>
           <li>Intenciones</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
            <li>La decadencia de la mentira</li>
            <li>Pluma, lápiz y veneno</li>
            <li>El crítico artista</li>
              <li>La verdad sobre las máscaras</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
           <li>El alma del hombre bajo el socialismo</li>
           <li>Frases y filosofías para uso de la juventud</li>
           <li>Algunas máximas para la instrucción de los súper-educados</li>
        </ul>
```